# CakePHP Custom Bakery

Tags: android, cakephp

I am using CakePHP as a tool to generate my android studio code.

My Android follow these patterns:

[image: My Android Folder]

As you can see

1. `Adapter` is where I put my adapter code
2. `List` is showing content as list in Activity
3. `Object` is the object

I have managed to make a custom bakery using CakePHP 2.7. However, I want to put the generated files in custom folders rather than `Model`, `Controller`, `View` folders, and if possible with `custom_name`, rather than cake default.

Is that possible?

[image: My CakePHP Code Generator]

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP is a framework that works thanks to certain basic conventions, like folder and file naming there is no easy way of renaming the files to your liking with CakePHP 2.

The bake tool in CakePHP 3 is substaintialy more flexible and allows you to create custom bake tasks that can be used to bake your custom files into the expected/desired locations. Take a look at how the existing tasks are created in https://github.com/cakephp/bake/tree/master/src/Shell/Task.